# Customizing QTabWidget with Style Sheets

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtabwidget

How can I style QTabWidget like is in the image below.

[image]

The problem is: if I set style sheet

```
QTabWidget:pane {
border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

then it looks like this:

[image: [qt can do][2].]

Comment: Isn't it as you expected to be? (the 2 images are the same)

Comment: Not the same. On the second image selected tabbar has an undesired bottom border.

Comment: Check this out: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar . Looks like you should be styling `QTabBar`.

Comment: Also if you solve it yourself with that, please write an answer yourself :)

Comment: Ok. Thank you for giving me right direction. Here is an aproximate style sheet. The key moment is QTabWidget::pane { top: -1px; }. It moves pane up (and it's top border) so it doesn't disturb, and  QTabBar::tab {margin-bottom: -1px; } as well, it hides appearing tabbar bottom and pane top differences.

Comment: QTabWidget::pane { border: 1px solid lightgray; top:-1px; background: rgb(245, 245, 245);; } 
QTabBar::tab { background: rgb(230, 230, 230); border: 1px solid lightgray; padding: 15px; } QTabBar::tab:selected { background: rgb(245, 245, 245); margin-bottom: -1px; }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reposting my comment. Here is the solution.

Ok. Thank you for giving me right direction. Here is an aproximate style sheet. The key moment is QTabWidget::pane { top: -1px; }. It moves pane up (and it's top border) so it doesn't disturb, and QTabBar::tab:selected {margin-bottom: -1px; } as well - it hides appearing tabbar bottom and pane top differences

```
QTabWidget::pane {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  top:-1px; 
  background: rgb(245, 245, 245);; 
} 

QTabBar::tab {
  background: rgb(230, 230, 230); 
  border: 1px solid lightgray; 
  padding: 15px;
} 

QTabBar::tab:selected { 
  background: rgb(245, 245, 245); 
  margin-bottom: -1px; 
}
```

Comment: The tab and pane seems not align, how to align them ?

Comment: @Wade Wang what do you mean exactly?

Comment: what i mean is like this : https://ibb.co/37q49LK, but i rechecked it, it is caused by its parent widget, i.e., this qtabwidget has a parent qtabwidget, and the parent qtabwidget set some stylesheet that makes the pane and tab unalign, then its children qtabwidget was affected.

Comment: Yes, if you set this stylesheet to clean QTabWidget, there will be no aligns.

Comment: *no aligns issues

Answer (score 4):

Styling the tabwidget:

```
QTabWidget::tab-bar {
   border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Styling tab:

```
QTabBar::tab {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
 }

 QTabBar::tab:selected {
  background: lightgray;
 }
```

Styling Panel:

```
QTabWidget::pane { 
   border: none;
}
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: But it still doesn't save us from the bottom line of the selected TabBar. This line is from the top pane border.

Comment: See the changes i made. Disable border, and custom the widget wich will be inside any tab.  User: QTabWidget::pane { 
   border: none;
}

Comment: I've tried this variant too. Even so, I need the whole pane border, except selected Tabbar. Thank you, but I've found the solution. I didn't know where to post, so I've posted it as comment to the first message, as was recommended by the help, so maybe it is badly visible.